# Docker Hub: Remote Build Trigger doesn't work

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I am trying to trigger image build via remote build trigger URL.
I have followed the [Docker Hub documentation](http://dockerdocs.gclearning.cn/v17.12/docker-hub/builds/#remote-build-triggers), but the actual Docker Hub UI option doesn't have the same options as described in the Docker Hub Docs for remote build trigger.

Docker Hub interface shown as per the docs:

[image]

My Docker Hub Interface:
[image]

I don't see token option anywhere.
Also, I tried hitting the trigger URL directly via browser, but that doesn't help either.

I guess I haven't understand this correctly, or there is some serious bug in Docker Hub especially for remote build trigger.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are following some unofficial documentation, which is outdated. Docker Hub redesigned this part some time ago. Now you don't need a token, because it's already included in the URL. But opening it in the browser is not enough, it must be a POST request, so you can try that from the command line with curl for example:

```
curl -X POST "<the-trigger-url-here>"
```